# Erro ao multiplicar valores nulos java

Tags: android

Estou tendo o seguinte problema: No meu projeto tem dois campo (editText) onde o usuário pode ou não inserir o valor.

EditText que recebe a quantidade `etCount`.

EditText que recebe o valor `etPriceUnit`.

Quando o `etCount` e o `etPriceUnit` apresentam o valor "null" na hora de fazer o cálculo o aplicativo fecha.

Isso provavelmente ocorre na tentativa de conversão para double e multiplicação de valores nulos na linha `double doubleTOTAL_PRICE_ITEM = (Double.parseDouble(stringCOUNT) * Double.parseDouble(stringPRICE_UNIT));`.

Tentei o seguinte para consertar tal problema:

```
if (stringCOUNT == null || stringPRICE_UNIT == null) {
    String stringTOTAL_PRICE_ITEM = "0";
} else {
    Double doubleTOTAL_PRICE_ITEM = (Double.parse.Double(stringCOUNT) * Double.parseDouble(stringPRICE_UNIT));
    String stringTOTAL_PRICE_ITEM = Double.toString(doubleTOTAL_PRICE_ITEM);
}
```

Mas não obtive sucesso. Eu não consigo utilizar a variável criada dentro do `if` na linha `result = crud.insertProduct(stringPRODUCT_NAME, stringCOUNT, stringPRICE_UNIT, stringTOTAL_PRICE_ITEM);`.

InsertProduct.class (**onClick**):

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Controller crud = new Controller(getBaseContext());
    EditText PRODUCT_NAME = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etProductName);
    EditText COUNT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCount);
    EditText PRICE_UNIT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPriceUnit);

    String stringPRODUCT_NAME = PRODUCT_NAME.getText().toString();
    String stringCOUNT = COUNT.getText().toString();
    String stringPRICE_UNIT = PRICE_UNIT.getText().toString();
    double doubleTOTAL_PRICE_ITEM = (Double.parseDouble(stringCOUNT) * Double.parseDouble(stringPRICE_UNIT));
    String stringTOTAL_PRICE_ITEM = Double.toString(doubleTOTAL_PRICE_ITEM);
    String result;
    if (stringPRODUCT_NAME.matches("")) {
        Toast.makeText(InsertProduct.this, "Você não inseriu o nome do produto.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    result = crud.insertProduct(stringPRODUCT_NAME, stringCOUNT, stringPRICE_UNIT, stringTOTAL_PRICE_ITEM);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(InsertProduct.this, Main.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Controller.class (**String insertProduct**):

```
public String insertProduct(String PRODUCT_NAME, String stringCOUNT, String stringPRICE_UNIT, String stringTOTAL_PRICE_ITEM) {

    ContentValues values;
    long result;

    db = database.getWritableDatabase();
    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CreateDB.PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_NAME);
    values.put(CreateDB.COUNT, stringCOUNT);
    values.put(CreateDB.PRICE_UNIT, stringPRICE_UNIT);
    values.put(CreateDB.TOTAL_PRICE_ITEM, stringTOTAL_PRICE_ITEM);

    result = db.insert(CreateDB.TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();

    if (result == -1)
        return "Erro ao inserir o produto.";
    else
        return "Produto inserido com sucesso!";
}
```

**@Update**
Problema resolvido. Segue a solução.

```
String stringCOUNT = COUNT.getText().toString(); //Pegando o valor do etCount e convertendo para string
String stringPRICE_UNIT = PRICE_UNIT.getText().toString();

if (stringCOUNT.matches("")) { //Se o EditText estiver vazio faça
    doubleCOUNT = 0; //Atribui o valor 0 se o EditText estiver vazio
} else { //Senão
    doubleCOUNT = Double.parseDouble(stringCOUNT); //Pega o valor do EditText e converte para double
}

if (stringPRICE_UNIT.matches("")) {
    doublePRICE_UNIT = 0;
} else {
    doublePRICE_UNIT = Double.parseDouble(stringPRICE_UNIT);
}
```

Comment: já tentou já inicializar o valor dessas variáveis como 0? de forma que se não forem modificados permaneçam valendo 0?

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso Olhá, não tinha pensado nisso, sou leigo demais. Poderia me dizer aonde posso declarar a variável com valor 0?

Comment: primeiro me parece equivocado você tentar realizar operações matemáticas com duas strings, declare stringCOUNT e stringPRICE_UNIT como int ou double.

Comment: Para declará-las com o valor 0 faça o seguinte `double stringCOUNT = 0` e `double stringPRICE_UNIT = 0`

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso eu declaro as variáveis no `public class InsertProduct`, na função `onCreate()` ou na função `onClick()`?

Comment: etCount e etPriceUnit são dois EditTexts correto?

Comment: Correto, já fiz as devidas conversões declarei no public class as seguintes variáveis `double doubleCOUNT = 0;` e `double doublePRICE_UNIT = 0;`, e converti para `double` na função `onClick()` `doubleCOUNT = Double.parseDouble(COUNT.getText().toString());` e `doublePRICE_UNIT = Double.parseDouble(PRICE_UNIT.getText().toString());`

Comment: fiz uma resposta para facilitar o seu entendimento e abreviar o seu código

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem para resolver o seu problema lhe darei uma maneira de setar o valor 0 tanto à variável **doubleCOUNT** quanto à variável **doublePRICE_UNIT** quando o editText não tiver nada escrito.

Adicione o método `addTextChangedListener()` para os seus dois editTexts (**etCount** e **etPriceUnit**) e faça o seguinte:

**etCount**:

```
etCount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (s.length()>0){ //essa condição só executará se o editText não estiver vazio e fará com que seja adicionado o valor digitado no editText à variável doubleCOUNT

            doubleCOUNT=Double.parseDouble(etCount.getText().toString().trim());

        }else{ //essa condição fará com que seja atribuído o valor 0 à variável doubleCOUNT se não tiver nada escrito no editText (etCount)

            doubleCount=0;
            etCount.setHint("0");

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Só fazer a mesma coisa com o etPriceUnit.

Lembrando que você não pode (pelo menos não para o que você está tentando fazer), multiplicar strings, pois variáveis STRINGS não estão preparadas para receber somente números, mas também letras e algarismos especiais.

Comment: Meu amigo, não sei como te agradecer, deu certo! Muito obrigado mesmo, você salvou minha semana. Só mais uma coisa o valor da multiplicação do `doubleCOUNT * doublePRICE_UNIT` está retornando um numero a mais, desnecessário, tipo 1.5 * 1.39 = 2.085. Só preciso de 2.08.

Comment: @GiovaniRodrigo na hora de aplicar o setText no textView vc faz o seguinte `textView.setText(String.format("%.2f", x/y));` quando você der o .format "ponto format" irá aparecer duas opções, utilize a que aparece `Locale l, String format, Object... args`. A expressão **x/y** foi uma expressão utilizada como exemplo, no seu código vc subtitui pela sua.

Comment: **x/y** seria o que exatamente? A variável que guarda o valor 2.085?

Comment: nn, x/y foi a expressão ki eu usei como exemplo, vc substitui por `doubleCOUNT * doublePRICE_UNIT`

Comment: Esses valores são exibidos através desse código `String[] field = new String[]{CreateDB.ID, CreateDB.PRODUCT_NAME, CreateDB.COUNT, CreateDB.PRICE_UNIT, CreateDB.TOTAL_PRICE_ITEM};  
int[] idViews = new int[]{R.id.tvId, R.id.tvProductName, R.id.tvCount, R.id.tvPriceUnit, R.id.tvTotalPriceItem};`

Comment: x/y no caso seria uma variável dividindo outro. Se você criou uma variável para armazenar o valor da multiplicação entre `doubleCOUNT` e `doublePRICE_UNIT` você faz a mesma coisa => `textView.setText(String.format("%.2f", variavelResultado))`

Comment: Cara mais um erro, se eu adiciono o item sem o valor, funciona perfeitamente, se eu adiciono o item com valor, o código transforma o valor para 0.

Comment: vc deve ter colocado para transformar para 0 em um dos dois escopos

Comment: Eu declarei a variável da seguinte maneira `double doubleCOUNT= 0;` e o `doublePRICE_UNIT` da mesma maneira. Mas eu declarei elas na `public class` e não no evento `onCreate` ou no `onClick`